# How to exit the app on back button press?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an app that needs move from screen 1 to screen two ....now when the user presses the back button..it should show a dialog box...if the user presses yes it has to exit...any help?the upper solutions don't work

Answer (score 13):

It seems like you can use [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html). You also need to pass a callback function which will indicate what will happen on pressing the back button.
In your case, you can add the code to show an [AlertDialog](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) which will ask for exit confirmation from the user.

You can simply wrap your Scaffold inside a WillPopScope.

Example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    child: /*Your scaffold widget*/
    onWillPop: () {
      return showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Confirm Exit"),
            content: Text("Are you sure you want to exit?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("YES"),
                onPressed: () {
                  SystemNavigator.pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("NO"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    );
    return Future.value(true);
  },
```

Comment: I don't know your answer isn't accepted. Really thanks